# Problems finding key/appending multiple values to a key in dictionary (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a dictionary that will save a value to a key and if the key is already existing, the value will be appended to the key to make a list of values. I am using python 3 so the dict.has_key method has deprecated, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Binary.txt:

```
N = N D
N = D
D = 0
D = 1



import sys
import string

#default length of 3
stringLength = 3

#get last argument of command line(file)
filename1 = sys.argv[-1]


#get a length from user
try:
    stringLength = int(input('Length? '))
    filename = input('Filename: ')
except ValueError:
    print("Not a number")

#checks
print(stringLength)
print(filename)

def str2dict(filename="Binary.txt"):
    result = {}
    with open(filename, "r") as grammar:
        #read file 
        lines = grammar.readlines()
        count = 0
        #loop through
        for line in lines:
            #append info 
            print(line)
            line = line.rstrip('\n')

            if line[0] in result:
                result[line[0]].append(line.split('=')[1])

            else: 

                result[line[0]] = line.split('=')[1]
            print (result)
    return result

print (str2dict("Binary.txt"))
```

Comment: It's deprecated because there's a better way: instead of `if dict.has_key(key)` use `if key in dict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), if the key exists we append the item, if it does not we will create the key and then append the item:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

d[key].append(item)
```

In your code:

```
result = defaultdict(list)
```

Then simply:

```
 result[line[0]].append(line.split('=')[1])
```

No need to check if the key exists.